# Google Maps for iOS or Android Offline Usage

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Are there any APIs in GoogleMaps that help developers to cache and then access maps of a particular town or city?

I have searched the web for this and found alternatives such as MapBox etc, but my interest is particularly in GoogleMaps.

Comment: we can able to access the google map at offline mode, but, you need to download sdk for offline access google map..https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing?csw=1

Comment: @harikrishnan Could you please point to some GoogleMaps APIs that will cache and can be used in the offline mode?? Or any Code Snippet would help.

Comment: @harikrishnan, Are you sure you can access the maps offline?

Comment: ya sure.. possibilities is there.. give some time.. am searching that offline sdk for this..

Comment: now try this api...http://mapswith.me/en/api.... code download link in this..https://github.com/mapswithme/api-android............... when i get Google offline sdk, i will post the link.... surely we will access the google maps offline mode.. when installed offline map sdk means,its done..